Mesh distorts while posing despite weight paint
The head mesh of this model distorts every time i move the left upper arm of the model. However, i also can't figure out why it is doing this. i checked the weightpaint of every single bone in relation to the mesh around six times at this point, but nothing but the upper arm is connected to the upper arm bone. i'll add an example picture and i'll attempt to add the model later too.



You need to select all the vertices head in Edit mode and Remove from All Groups. The weird thing is that you need to do it twice (???!?). Then assign to the vertex group called headneo. Also don't forget to apply the scale and rotation of your objects.

